# custom html in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I'm trying to call a javascript function which uses custom HTML as seen below.
This somehow doesn't get recognised if called from a javascript function. The code within the function below works well if executed outside the function. Any help on this?
code:

```
<button class="button" 
onclick="javascript:validate();">Submit</button>
<p id="h2"></p>
<script>
function validate()
{
strVar2 = "<ag-dashboard>";
strVar2 += "        <div class='col-md-6'>";
strVar2 += "            <ag-chart name='writepending'>";
strVar2 += "            <ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for 
Today' ></ag-option>";
strVar2 += "            </ag-chart>";
strVar2 += "      </div>";
strVar2 += "        <div class='col-md-6'>";
strVar2 += "            <ag-chart name='writepending'>";
strVar2 += "            <ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for             
Yesterday' ></ag-option>";
strVar2 += "            </ag-chart>";
strVar2 += "      </div>";
strVar2 += "</ag-dashboard>";

document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = strVar2;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, but sorry to say it doesn't work still. There's another line in the code which I have not published since it has internal data. But, I just want to know if this is an acceptable approach or not? Because, I'm unable to get it working :( The same code if executed without the function, produces desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`<button class="button" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17227262)

Comment: He didn't ask for clarification.  If the answer doesn't work, so be it.  Your comment serves no purpose.

Comment: His answer is not really an answer as it currently is. First the answer does not provide any description why the fix is working. Also the answer is more like a "try this" comment rather then a real answer. For more information you can consult "how to answer" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Dude, if you know it doesn't work, then why don't you help the OP instead of tone policing?

Comment: Dude if you don't know if it is working why even post an answer?

Comment: From your own link: "Answers don't have to be exhaustive or infallible, they just need to try to answer the question.".  Get a life.

Comment: I don't really care if your answer is working, that was not my point. All I'm saying is that your question was reported for lack of quality and came through my review queue and I agreed, that the question lacks quality :-)

Comment: I didn't post the question.  Are you drunk?

Comment: That was a mistake, I meant your "answer" came through the queue...If you don't see that your answer is of very low quality, then I don't see the point of a continued discussion.

Comment: Get a life.  Over and out.

Comment: If I look at your current questions...they speak for them selfs and your understanding or quality...

Comment: I appreciate the childish downvote you gave my question that hasn't been bothered with for a few days now.  Showing real class there, mate.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tidy your code better.

First, you have to fix the `onlick="javascript:validate();"` it should be like this

```
<button class="button" onclick="validate()">Submit</button>
```

Second, you had syntax errors at "Activity for Today" and "Activity for Yesterday"

Try this, it should work.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RZdQWM

You won't see any output, because i'm not sure what to expect, but check inspect element and the divs and other elements you have are there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this js fiddle [append html](https://jsfiddle.net/lamp03/xLzzfj4f/)

JAVSCRIPT :-

```
function validate() {
        strVar2 = "<ag-dashboard>";
        strVar2 += "<div class='col-md-6'>";
        strVar2 += "<ag-chart name='writepending'>";
        strVar2 += "<ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for Today' ></ag-option>";
        strVar2 += "</ag-chart>";
        strVar2 += "</div>";
        strVar2 += "<div class='col-md-6'>";
        strVar2 += "<ag-chart name='writepending'>";
        strVar2 += "<ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for Yesterday' ></ag-option>";
        strVar2 += "</ag-chart>";
        strVar2 += "</div>";
        strVar2 += "</ag-dashboard>";
        document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = strVar2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working totally fine mate.

```
<button class="button" onclick="javascript:validate();"> Submit</button>
<p id="h2"></p>
<script>
  function validate() {
    strVar2 = "<ag-dashboard>";
    strVar2 += "<div class='col-md-6'>";
    strVar2 += "<ag-chart name='writepending'>";
    strVar2 += "<ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for Today' ></ag-option>";
    strVar2 += "</ag-chart>";
    strVar2 += "</div>";
    strVar2 += "<div class='col-md-6'><h1>hey</h1>";
    strVar2 += "<ag-chart name='writepending'>";
    strVar2 += "<ag-option name='title.text' value='Activity for Yesterday' ></ag-option>";
    strVar2 += "</ag-chart>";
    strVar2 += "</div>";
    strVar2 += "</ag-dashboard>";
    document.getElementById("h2").innerHTML = strVar2;
  }
</script>
```

I have added `h1` saying hey, copy this above code and see it working. Hope it helps.